# Kotlin Property items should be initialized before get

Tags: android, kotlin

```
    var items: Int by Delegates.notNull<Int>()

    db.collection("Testdatabase").get().addOnSuccessListener{ snap->
        items=snap.size()
    }
    Log.i("items",items.toString())
```

and it says

```
Property items should be initialized before get
```

I have to use 'items' variable as a size of the snapshot.
I searched some google but I can't figure out..
Can any one help please?

Comment: You must assign some value to `items` before you use them inside the `Log`. Remember that the `Log` statement will be executed first due to synchronous execution and then the `items=snap.size()` line

So you must assign some value to items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because your `addOnSuccessListener` takes some time to get data. So in this example, you need to put your log statement inside `addOnSuccessListener` and you will be fine

Comment: Thank you Thank you for telling me the reason!!